# A faster way to merge a list of 1D-arrays?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, array-merge

I have a function `distance` that take a natural number as an input and return a 1-D array of length 199. My goal is to merge all the arrays `distance(0)`, ..., `distance(499)`. My code to do so is as follows:

```
import numpy as np 

np.random.seed(42)
n = 200
d = 500
sample = np.random.uniform(size = [n, d])

def distance(i):
    value = list(sample[i, 0:3])
    temp = value - sample[(i + 1):n, 0:3]
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(temp**2, axis = 1))

temp = [distance(i) for i in range(n - 1)]
result = [j for i in temp for j in i]
```

Because I work with large `d`, I want to optimize as good as possible. I would like to ask for a faster way to merge such arrays.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does `np.hstack(temp)` help?

Comment: @hpaulj the syntax of  `np.hstack(temp)` is clearer, but its speed is approximately the same as `[j for i in temp for j in i]`.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the pairwise distance? Or is it just a mock-up example?

Comment: @hpaulj because `np.hstack` is from package numpy and efficiently optimized. I think it's hard to get any better ^^

Comment: @QuangHoang You are exactly right. I'm trying to compute pairwise distance in the hypercube. I'm very surprised that you figured my goal even though I simplify the code so much.

Comment: On my system, `np.concatenate(temp)` is a bit faster than `np.hstack`. That said, pairwise distance can be done in broadcasting manner.

Comment: @QuangHoang This is the first time I heard about "broadcasting manner". Could you please elaborate so that I can search further?

Comment: @LAD see my answer for a solution. And [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is the official documentation of broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to compute the pairwise distance:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
dist = cdist(sample[:,:3], sample[:,:3])
```

Of course you get back a symmetric array with all pairwise distances. To get your `result`, you can do:

```
result = dist[np.triu_indices(n,k=1)]
```

---

Regarding the broadcasting comment, `cdist` will do something similar to this:

```
dist = np.sum((sample[None,:,:3]-sample[:,None,:3])**2, axis=-1)**0.5
```

---

For reference, below is the run time for each:

```
%%timeit -n 100
temp = [distance(i) for i in range(n - 1)]
result = [j for i in temp for j in i]
6.41 ms ± 197 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
temp = [distance(i) for i in range(n - 1)]
result = np.hstack(temp)
4.86 ms ± 295 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
temp = [distance(i) for i in range(n - 1)]
result = np.concatenate(temp)
4.28 ms ± 175 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
dist = np.sum((sample[None,:,:3]-sample[:,None,:3])**2, axis=-1)**0.5
result = dist[np.triu_indices(n,k=1)]
1.47 ms ± 61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit -n 100
dist = cdist(sample[:,:3], sample[:,:3])
result = dist[np.triu_indices(n,k=1)]
415 µs ± 26.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Wow wow your solution of `scipy.spatial.distance` reduces the total time from `12.603490829467773` to `1.9831750392913818`. It's really awesomeee. You always come up with elegant solutions.

Comment: It's fantastic ^^

Comment: May I ask how you generate the timing for each command and obtain such display of result?

Comment: @LAD `%%timeit` is the magic command in Jupyter. Each block above is a separate cell with its output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!